# Replace Typing with a variable

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently constructing a small program that can read Excel files in to a data table and does some alterations in it. It works fine, but only for the current file I am using seeing the table structure in the Excel file will be different every time.

I've tried looking for a solution but the problem is that I don't know the correct terminology to describe my problem.

```
DataTableA= DataTableB.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<double>("IDNumber"))
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var row = DtSet.NewRow();
        row["IDNumber"] = g.Key;
        row["Value"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Value"));                   
        return row;
    }).CopyToDataTable();
```

What I want is to replace the `double` in `.GroupBy(r => r.Field<double>("IDNumber"))` and `row["Value"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Value"));` with a variable.

So that before this code runs I can check the field type and assign the right one.

Also if anybody has a other way of creating a new data table from an old one using group by/sum functions at run time they are more then welcome.

Comment: try ```row[1]```

Comment: You're probably looking for _generics_ https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: In case you want to parametrize Field<T> at runtime, you won't be able to do so, since generic type parameter must be resolvable at compilation time

Comment: @tim so it's not possible to first load in an Excel sheet, check what types the columns have and then run this code with the correct typing?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel i have taken a look on that link but i can't see how this would give me my desired results, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

```
DataTableA= DataTableB.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => r.Field<double>("IDNumber"))
           .Select(g =>
           {
               var row = DtSet.NewRow();
               row["IDNumber"] = g.Key;
               row["Value"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<dynamic>("Value"));                   
               return row;
           }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I just tried it, and got this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" I think it's because some of the values in the double column would also fit in to an int.

Comment: What are the possible types you expect here?

Comment: Most of them would be Datetime, String, and Double with Int also being a possibility. The purpose of the new application is to work for a wide array of different excel sheets.

Comment: You can handle the int and double conversion with a cast but not sure about the others. because, even though `dynamic` will get you past static type checks, the code should still be valid (like `Sum`) for inferred type. At the end of the day, excel sheet needs to be clean.

Comment: The problem is that the user can do a lot of different excel sheets and i can't but to many restriction on that sadly.